# How to enable SSL in ActiveMQ Artemis for MQTT protocol based on keystore and truststore

Tags: ssl, mqtt, activemq-artemis

I have installed ActiveMQ Artemis in Linux and configured `broker.xml`. I am using a certificate, but ActiveMQ Artemis uses keystore and truststore. How to create those and how to enable SSL for MQTT protocol?

Below shows configuration broker.xml

```xml
<acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true
        sslEnabled=true;
        keyStorePath=home/certs/server-ks/server1.p12;keyStorePassword=abc@1234;
        trustStorePath=home/certs/server-ks/server1.p12;
        trustStorePassword=abc@1234;needClientAuth=true
</acceptor>
```

I have converted a certificate (.pem) to keystore and truststore

```
keytool -import -alias rootCA -trustcacerts -file certs/ca.pem -keystore certs/activeMQ-truststore.jks

openssl pkcs12 -inkey certs/server-cert/server1.pem -in certs/server-cert/server1.pem -name server1 -export -out certs/server-ks/server1.p12

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass abc@1234 -destkeystore certs/server-ks/server-keystore1.jks -srckeystore certs/server-ks/server1.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

As above same I have created/converted for client keystore.

I need to connect broker using MQTT.FX client with self signed client keystore.

How to achieve this I am getting confused. Please help me if any one have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a self-signed configuration typically you'll create a certificate for both the broker and the client, export each, and then import the broker's cert into the client's truststore and import the client's cert into the broker's truststore. You can do all this using Java's `keytool` command.

Take a look at the example that ships with ActiveMQ Artemis in the `examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled-dual-authentication` directory. It demonstrates how to do this, e.g.:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore server-side-keystore.jks -storepass secureexample -keypass secureexample -dname "CN=ActiveMQ Artemis Server, OU=Artemis, O=ActiveMQ, L=AMQ, S=AMQ, C=AMQ" -keyalg RSA
keytool -export -keystore server-side-keystore.jks -file server-side-cert.cer -storepass secureexample
keytool -import -keystore client-side-truststore.jks -file server-side-cert.cer -storepass secureexample -keypass secureexample -noprompt
keytool -genkey -keystore client-side-keystore.jks -storepass secureexample -keypass secureexample -dname "CN=ActiveMQ Artemis Client, OU=Artemis, O=ActiveMQ, L=AMQ, S=AMQ, C=AMQ" -keyalg RSA
keytool -export -keystore client-side-keystore.jks -file client-side-cert.cer -storepass secureexample
keytool -import -keystore server-side-truststore.jks -file client-side-cert.cer -storepass secureexample -keypass secureexample -noprompt
```

Your `acceptor` will need both `sslEnabled=true` and `needClientAuth=true`.